# Are arguments variables or constants?

Tags: javascript

Let me show you a very simple example:

```
function abc(x, y, z){
 x = x.toLowerCase();
 return x;
}
```

Can I change the value of arguments of a function?

Comment: Yes you can change

Comment: Did you tried? Yes, it is changeable. For more information you can check https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_function_parameters.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, here is how to.

```js
function abc(x, y, z){
    x = x.toLowerCase();
    return x;
}

abc = function(x = 'totally new way') {
    return x;
}

alert(abc());
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are `variables`

```js
function foo(x){
    x = x.toLowerCase();
    return x;
}

console.log(foo("ABC"))
```

If they were constants... you wouldn't be able to set its value in the first place rendering the parameters useless

Comment: arguments can not be a constant.

Comment: I'm not sure if he was talking about arguments values or arguments list ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
function abc(x, y, z) {  return x.toLowerCase() }

console.log( abc('HeLLo') );
```